# gcc options for pure executable file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, kernel

I'm developing with hobbyOS's bootloader and kernel

I do not mean a binary file. I know it as well (by objcopy or link optiob) as servel options like `-nostdlib` and `-ffreestanding`. What I want to express is that `gcc` always generate the file with advanced features like `.eh_frame` section and GLT support (maybe in the future there will be more)，I can disable it by proper option.

The problem is: can I disable all of it totally and generate a pure executable file which includes only essential `.text`, `.data`, `.rodata` and `.bss` sections.

Comment: The o/s determines what is acceptable — it has to interpret the 'pure executable'.  So, you need to review your o/s manuals to see what it handles.  Then, maybe, you can tweak your platform-specific cross-compiler into doing what you need — but that should be clear from the o/s manuals anyway.  Or maybe you can run the compiler on the o/s; in that case, the compiler should be producing what you need anyway.

Comment: You might like [this article](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).